# Adiing embedded Resource in Visual Studio throws error - Specified argument is out of range

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I need to include an embedded resource in my .Net Project. It is an .exe file. I just started a blank project in Visual Studio Professional 2019. Next I added the .exe file by right-click --> add an existing file and so on. I also changed the build action to embedded resource.

I am doing nothing else. When I just start the blank project by clicking on green play button on the top the project cant be build. The error message is the following (German)

> Fehler    CS1566  Fehler beim Lesen der Ressource "somefile.exe": "Das
> angegebene Argument liegt außerhalb des gültigen
> Wertebereichs.    MyProjectName
> C:\Users\Kerem\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject"

In English it is something like `

> CS1566 Error reading the resource. The specified argument is out of
> range.

Can someone please tell me what the problem may be.

My .csproj file looks like following.

Interestingly the prject can be build if i dont declare the resource as embedded resource in the build action. But I guess I have to do that, to be able to copy the file to the working directory or somewhere else and start it.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

    
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="res\ABC_12.34_German_Installer.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="res\ABC_12.34_German_Installer.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>  

</Project>
```

Comment: Do you have net core 3.1 installed?  Check Control Panel Installed software and see if core 3.1 is installed.

Comment: Yes it is installed. I guess the file is simply too large. It works with another smaller .exe file

Comment: The version of Net has to be exactly the same for the code to always work.  It is possible that some code will work when Net is not exactly the same.  The larger the program the less likely that different versions of Net will run the code sucessfully.  This problem sounds like either the version of Net is different or the compiler options are different between the exe and the Net you are using.